# How to fix / prevent JS code in asp.net core view to be escaped

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.Net Core project where on one page I am getting some 'data' that is being pulled from a database with the intention of being written into a view inside a block of JavaScript.  The text has quotes and ampersands in it, and is valid JS.  The code is being written in the view in the following manner:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Other script

    <text>
    @item.MyData   // The data I'm writing, if I set a breakpoint here
                   // on the server side when the view is run,
                   // the text is as I expect it to be, with quotes 
                   // preceded by a \, less than signs, ampersands, etc.
    </text>

</script>
```

However, when this string gets to the page, the quotes, less than / greater than, and everything else is escaped out, and I am getting " & and the like.  Not sure how/where these are getting escaped.  Any way to prevent this, or unwind it?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `@(new MvcHtmlString(item.MyData))` outside of the text block should work unless that's not available in Core

Comment: Did the trick - I actually used HtmlString, which I think is a replacement.  Still, I wouldn't have thought of this.  If youwant to make this an answer I'll mark it as such.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Ran into this myself a while back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `IHtmlString` which indicates that the string contained is already encoded.

`@(new HtmlString(item.MyData))`