# why JavaScript code changes " ' " character

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

When I insert a string into the JavaScript code I get instead the character **'** ---> **& # x27;**

For example-

```
string= ['orange','apple','mango'] --> [&#x27;orange&#x27;,&#x27;apple&#x27;,&#x27;mango&#x27;]
```

**cs code-**

```
            foreach (var item in _context.Products)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(allProducts))
            {
                allProducts += ",";
            }
            allProducts += "'" + item.ProductName + "'";


        }
        AllProducts = "[" + allProducts + "]";
```

**javascript-**

```
var products =@Model.AllProducts;
```

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45903446/218196 ?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'HtmlString' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `allProducts += "'" + item.ProductName + "'"` is not proper string escaping and will break as soon as the product name contains an apostrophe, linebreak, or else. Depending on where the value comes from, this could well be a XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use @Html.Raw method to wraps HTML markup from the string representation of an Object in an HtmlString, without HTML-encoding the string representation.

More details, you could refer to below test demo codes:

```
@section scripts{ 
    <script>
        $(function () {


          
            var products = @Html.Raw(Model.AllProducts);
 

    });
    </script>

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: `AllProducts = "['</script>']"`